# R - use global variables to solve ode45 similar to MATLAB/GNU Octave

Tags: r, matlab, global-variables, octave

I am attempting to rewrite code from GNU Octave/MATLAB in R version 3.3.1. In the original code, A and B were set as global variables in a function and then in the script file both A and B were set as global variables.

In R, this is the error message that I receive when I attempt to use the `ode45` function:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z1' not found

Can anyone suggest how to set the global variables in R as was done in the GNU Octave/MATLAB code?

Thank you.

---

R code follows

```
#list.R is a wrapper for list used to replicate the GNU Octave/MATLAB syntax


source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ggrothendieck/gsubfn/master/R/list.R")

install.load::load_package("ramify", "pracma")

GRT <- function (t, x) {
         A  <- A
         B  <- B
         z1 <- x[1, 1]; z2 <- x[2, 1]; z3 <- x[3, 1]; X <- mat("z1; z2; z3")
         xd <- A * X + B * exp(-t) * sin(400 * t)
}


A <- -mat("2, 3, 2; 1, 5, 3; 2, 3, 1")
B <- mat("1; 3; 2")

ts <- 0.0
tf <- 10
X0 <- c(1, 0, -1)

list[t, x] <- ode45(GRT, ts, tf, X0)

P <- mat("t, x")

matplot(t, x, xlab = "time - (s)", ylab = "x")
```

I am using GNU Octave, version 3.8.1 to run the code. The following code in GNU Octave/MATLAB is what I have attempted to replicate above:

```
function xd=GRT(t,x)
global A B
z1=x(1,1); z2=x(2,1);z3=x(3,1);X=[z1;z2;z3];
xd =A*X+B*exp(-t)*sin(400*t);
endfunction % only needed for GNU Octave

global A B
A = -[2,3,2;1,5,3;2,3,1];
B = [1;3;2];
ts = 0.0;
tf = 10;
T=[ts,tf]; X0=[1,0,-1];
[t,x] = ode45(@GRT,T,X0)
P = [t,x];
plot(t,x)
xlabel('time - (s)');
ylabel('x');
```

This is `X`:

```
X =

1.0000
1.0016
1.0043
```

The size of `t` is 809 rows, 1 column. This is a partial look at `t`.

```
t =

0.00000
0.00305
0.00632
0.00928
0.01226
0.01524
0.01840
0.02186
0.02482
0.02778
0.03079
0.03391
0.03750
0.04046
0.04344
0.04646
0.04959
0.05321
0.05618
```

The size of `x` is 809 rows, 3 columns. This is a partial look at `x`.

```
x =

1.0000e+00   0.0000e+00  -1.0000e+00
1.0016e+00   1.0937e-02  -9.9982e-01
1.0043e+00   2.5810e-02  -9.9752e-01
1.0040e+00   3.1460e-02  -1.0007e+00
1.0012e+00   2.9337e-02  -1.0090e+00
9.9908e-01   2.9132e-02  -1.0161e+00
1.0001e+00   3.8823e-02  -1.0170e+00
1.0028e+00   5.4307e-02  -1.0148e+00
1.0026e+00   6.0219e-02  -1.0178e+00
9.9979e-01   5.8198e-02  -1.0260e+00
9.9739e-01   5.7425e-02  -1.0336e+00
9.9809e-01   6.6159e-02  -1.0351e+00
1.0007e+00   8.1786e-02  -1.0331e+00
1.0004e+00   8.7669e-02  -1.0361e+00
9.9753e-01   8.5608e-02  -1.0444e+00
9.9500e-01   8.4599e-02  -1.0522e+00
```

This is the expected plot:

[image: GRT plot]

Comment: First, a warning -- using global variables is considered very bad practice in programming. Having said that, could you show your expected result (the plot from Octave)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but in MATLAB what @Hack-R says holds very true. It's very error prone and highly difficult to debug (e.g. you set the global's value, then in some other function you accidentally overwrite it, then the first functions goes wrong, whilst not knowing why.)

Comment: So in that function `GRT` you're using `x`, which I presume is `X0`, but the dimensions you're trying to reference by index don't make sense because `X0` is just a 3 element vector.

Comment: Also which object did you want to pass to `GRT` as `t`? `ts` or `tf`?

Comment: It seems that `mat()` has trouble finding the variables `z1` etc. when called withing a function. Try to use `X <- matrix(c(z1, z2, z3), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)` instead. And then I assume that `A * X` is supposed to be a matrix multiplication. This is written as `A %*% X` in R. If I make these two changes, the code runs through. Whether the output is the expected one, I can not say...

Comment: @Stibu He never created `z1` because the code was wrong. It has no trouble finding it when it's created properly. Also it's never returned.

Comment: @Hack-R It has, if I run the code. Also the code from your answer produces that same error message, when I run it.

Comment: @Stibu I don't know what you're doing wrong but my code doesn't produce any errors. It gives a nice plot.

Comment: @Hack-R That's weird... By the way, why are you returning `z1` from `GRT()`? Shouldn't it be `xd`?

Comment: @Stibu @Hack-R @Adriann  I want to thank each of you for your comments. I have revised the GNU Octave/MATLAB code (GRT should have been called as an anonymous function), I have included the values of `X`, `t`, and `x`, and I have included the expected plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer uses some elements from the various comments and the answer by Hack-R.

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ggrothendieck/gsubfn/master/R/list.R")

install.load::load_package("ramify", "pracma")

GRT <- function (t, x) {

z1 <- x[1, 1]; z2 <- x[2, 1]; z3 <- x[3, 1]; X <- matrix(data = c(z1,  
z2, z3), nrow = 3, ncol = 1)

xd <- A %*% X + B * exp(-t) * sin(400 * t)

return(xd)
}


A <- -mat("2, 3, 2; 1, 5, 3; 2, 3, 1")

B <- mat("1; 3; 2")

ts <- 0.0

tf <- 10

X0 <- c(1, 0, -1)

list[t, x] <- ode45(GRT, ts, tf, X0, atol = 0.000001, hmax = 1.0)

matplot(t, x, xlab = "time - (s)", ylab = "x", type = "l")
```

[image: ode45 plot in R]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ggrothendieck/gsubfn/master/R/list.R")

pacman::p_load(ramify, pracma) # I use pacman, you don't have to

GRT <- function (t, x) {
  X <- mat("z1; z2; z3")
  xd <- A %*% X + B %*% exp(-t) * sin(400 * t)
  return(z1)
}


A <- -mat("2, 3, 2; 1, 5, 3; 2, 3, 1")
B <- mat("1; 3; 2")

ts <- 0.0
tf <- 10
X0 <- c(1, 0, -1)
z1 <- X0[1]
z2 <- X0[2]
z3 <- X0[3] 

GRT(t=ts,x=X0)

list[t, x] <- ode45(GRT, ts, tf, X0)

P <- mat("t, x")

matplot(t, x, xlab = "time - (s)", ylab = "x")
```

Changes made:

1. Used matrix multiplication operator in `GRT` instead of scalar multiplication
2. Fixed the indexing of `X0` (called `x` in your function)
3. Commented out 2 unnecessary lines from `GRT`
4. Added a `return` statement to `GRT`

I had to make some assumptions about what you were trying to do where the syntax was wrong, like with the indexing of `X0`. Since I didn't have the example output plot from Octave to reference (and I can't get your code to run in my Octave CLI) I can't tell if those assumptions were correct, and if not my plot may be different.

This is the resulting plot from the code above:

[image]

Final note: It looks like you never used the result of `P <- mat("t, x")` anyway, but I don't think it does what you think it's doing anyway, based on the resulting object.